# ¿Como usar una variable en la funcion update de Transact SQL dentro de un trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Lo que quiero lograr es recorrer cada columna de una tabla y verificar si tiene un cambio con la funcion update(colum), pero al parecer toma la variable donde guardo la columna  como un argumento valido.

```
DECLARE @field INT ,
       @maxfield INT ,
       @fieldname VARCHAR(128) ,
       @TableName VARCHAR(128) ,
       @SelectUpdate Varchar(100) = 'Select '

SELECT         @field = 0, 
       @maxfield = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
WHILE @field < @maxfield
BEGIN
       SELECT @field = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
               AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @field

               SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                       WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
                       AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @field

        IF (UPDATE(@fieldname))
        BEGIN
            if (@field = 1)
            select @SelectUpdate = @SelectUpdate + @fieldname
            else
            select @SelectUpdate = @SelectUpdate +', ' +@fieldname
        END
END
```

Comment: Tenes un BEGIN Colgado antes de SELECT @fieldname, eso es a propósito o error de tipeo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente no puedes usar una variable para indicar el nombre de columna en la clausula `UPDATE`. Lo que si podrías hacer es usar [`COLUMNS_UPDATED()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql) junto con `syscolumns` para obtener los nombres de las columnas actualizadas. La siguiente es una sencilla prueba de concepto:

```
-- Tabla de ejemplo
CREATE TABLE Prueba (
    COL1    INT,
    COL2    INT,
    COL3    INT,
    COL4    INT
)

-- Tabla para registrar que campos fueron actualizados
CREATE TABLE PruebaLog (
    Camposactualizados VARCHAR(MAX)
)

GO

-- Trigger para el insert y update
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Prueba ON Prueba
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @Columns_Updated VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT  @Columns_Updated = ISNULL(@Columns_Updated + ', ', '') + name
        FROM    syscolumns
        WHERE   id = OBJECT_ID('Prueba')
        AND     CONVERT(VARBINARY,REVERSE(COLUMNS_UPDATED())) & POWER(CONVERT(BIGINT, 2), colorder - 1)  > 0

    INSERT INTO PruebaLog(Camposactualizados)
        VALUES(@Columns_Updated)
GO

-- El insert actualiza todas las columnas
INSERT INTO Prueba (COL1, COL2) VALUES (1,2)
SELECT  *
    FROM PruebaLog

/* Resultado:
Camposactualizados 
----------------------
COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
*/

-- El update actualiza solo ciertas columnas
UPDATE Prueba SET COL2=3
SELECT  *
    FROM PruebaLog

/* Resultado:
Camposactualizados 
----------------------
COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
COL2
*/

DROP TRIGGER Trigger_Prueba
DROP TABLE Prueba
DROP TABLE PruebaLog
GO
```

[`COLUMNS_UPDATED()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql) retorna un `varbinary` con un patrón de bits que indica el estado de actualización de cada columna en un operación de `INSERT` o `UPDATE` de un determinado `trigger`.